# (margin/padding)-right does not create space for overflow container

Tags: html, css

For some reason, in an overflown container, the padding on the right side is not shown.

```css
.parent {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: auto; 
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.child {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

I expected the orange color to show up when I scrolled to the very end (right)

Comment: because it's overlowing, it's logical ... if you can put padding so you won't have overflow

Comment: @TemaniAfif I thought that it would take into consideration the child's size then just add more spacing to it.

Comment: no, padding remain inside the element, and actually you are overflowing the width that include the padding (check dev console to see that the padding exist and you are on top of it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start without applying any `overflow` property. We clearly have the element outside of it's parent container (add padding of the container will remain inside):

```css
.parent {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  padding:15px;
}

.child {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Now by adding `overflow:scroll` or `overflow:auto` you will simply add the scroll to see the overflowing part and you won't have the padding as excepted:

```css
.parent {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow:auto;
  padding:15px;
}

.child {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Same logic with the margin right. When the element is overflowing there is no room to add margin between the inner element and the parent element.

Comment: any tip on getting what I'm looking for then? or will I just have to add some kind of vertical spacing inside the child?

Answer (score 1):

I have checked in also Mozilla Firefox. and it's working fine.

```css
.parent {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: auto;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.child {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 10px;
 display: inline-block;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use below CSS. It's working for me.

```
.parent {
    background-color: orange;
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
.child {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```